# angular 2, http service not requesting

Tags: angularjs, http, get

I am trying to use get method of http service, but nothing is working.

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

...

constructor (private http: Http) {}

...

    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map((...a) => console.log(a))
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

I cant even see nothing in network related to my url.

What can be wrong?

Comment: You probably forgot to subscribe to the returned observable. That's what sends the request.

Comment: oops.
I still not used to that observables.
I was expecting map will show something.
But probabli as soon as I not subscribe nothing will be called, right?

Comment: Right. map() just returns a new observable which will, when the an event is emitted by the first one, trasform this event. Subscribing is what sends the request.